# Correct syntax when using Php variable in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

This should not be so difficult but I keep getting a mySQL syntax error for every iteration I tried for inserting a Php variable in a ORDER BY clause.  My line is:

```
...ORDER BY '$choice', substring_index(Name, " ", -1);
```

I tried putting the variable $choice in double quotes, brackets, parenthesis, quotes and parenthesis, nothing worked.  What am I missing?

Comment: The order by must used a column name of your table

Comment: what value `$choice` contains?

Comment: ORDER BY column_name

Comment: Are you implying it is impossible to use a variable in the ORDER BY clause?

Comment: I am afraid the only way I can accomplish what I am trying to do is to use three variations of the entire mySQL statement and assign each to a $sql= selected on the the basis of my conditions in a "if, elseif".  Not elegant coding but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case`:

```
order by (case when '$choice' = col1 then col1 end),
         (case when '$choice' = col2 then col2 end),
         . . .
         substring_index(Name, ' ', -1)
```

Multiple `case` is better than one, because different types are more easily supported.

The alternative is dynamic SQL.

Comment: @user3520372 . . .  Did you replace `...` with more `case` statements?  Did you put your column names in for `col1` and `col2`?

Answer (score 0):

Try below use cases,

1.if your column names contain spaces then,

```
ORDER BY `{$choice}`
```

2.if it is a simple string in php variable then,

```
 $choice = "your_column_name";
  SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY $choice ASC
```

Comment: If I just try to use $choice there is no error but the variable is treated as a constant.

Comment: did you use backtick(`)?

Comment: backtick doesn't work.  It treats the variable as a constant.

Answer (score 0):

I encase my whole query in double quotes, then you can use the variables like so

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tables ORDER BY $orderparams"
```

Comment: Using double quotes to enclose my $sql = statement gives me a syntax error.  I must use single quotes for the statement.

Answer (score -1):

It could be the way you are declaring your string that is the problem.  Using the wrong type of quotes for variable interpolation will cause it to fail and parse the variable name literally.  Variable interpolation only works when you have a string with double quotes.  For example:

```
$myVariable = "hello world";
echo "This is a php variable --> $myVariable";
// will print "This is a php variable --> hello world"
echo 'This is the literal string --> $myVariable';
// will print "This is the literal string --> $myVariable"
```

Another way to accomplish the same interpolation as the first example with no chance of it being interpolated wrong is:

```
echo "This is a php variable between characters abc{$myVariable}def";
// will print "This is a php variable between characters abchello worlddef"
```

Not sure if that is the problem since your question lacks the context of declaring the query string, but it is something to watch for when using php.

Comment: The problem seems to clearly be related to the syntax of using a variable in the mySQL statement.  If I replace it with a constant there is no error.

Comment: It would help to see more context of how you are declaring the variable and query string so that we can see if that is a problem or if it is an issue with the mysql syntax.  If you print the query string and it runs a valid query on the mysql command line then it is a php problem not a syntax problem.